# Parsing Object by @PostMapping, using access to methods

Tags: java, spring, json-deserialization, spring5

i tried to parse request body into Ship object

```
    @PostMapping("/ships")
    public Ship createShip(@RequestBody Ship ship){

        return ship;
    }
```

And when Ship object was deserialize, spring use only injection values to fields. But I want that spring use setters for this fields.

I tried to add annotation @JsonSetter to setters and it works well. But i think it bad way.

```
    @Entity
    public class Ship {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        private String name;
        private String planet;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @JsonSetter
        public void setName(String name) {
            if(name == null || name == "") throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while setting name. Can't be null and empty");
            if(name.length() > 50) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while setting name. Can't be mere than 50 chars");
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPlanet() {
            return planet;
        }

        @JsonSetter
        public void setPlanet(String planet) {
            if(planet == null || planet == "") throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while setting planet. Can't be null and empty");
            if(planet.length() > 50) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while setting planet. Can't be mere than 50 chars");
            this.planet = planet;
        }

    }
```

Maybe exist some annotations like this:

```
    createShip(@RequestBody(access = METHODS) Ship ship)
```

or

```
    @Entity 
    @JsonDeserialize(access=METHODS)
    public class Ship {
```

Comment: *"But i think it bad way."* Why?

Comment: the description of this annotation says that it is used to indicate the setter method if it has a non-standard name. But it does not say that it forces us to use the method instead of directly entering the field. And I don’t understand why it works for me like that, and it scares me

Comment: "May be you should not use @Entity class as Request/ Response classes", create a new class 'ShipRequest' with same fields and use it as RequestBody class

Comment: Actually, the documentation of [`@JsonSetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) says: *"Annotation that can be used to define a non-static, single-argument method to be used as a "setter" for a logical property as an alternative to **recommended `JsonProperty` annotation**"*. --- So you should use the `@JsonProperty` in the getter method instead.

Comment: I remove Entity and create POJO, but methods still not use :(

Comment: Yes, JsonProperty works as JsonSetter for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your Ship class as POJO and validate conditions in setters can be organized as spring validation feature mentioned in [spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation).

Validating bean using spring -

1. define custom validator

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;


@Component
public class ShipValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Ship.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
         Ship ship = (Ship) obj;
         String name = ship.getName();
         String planet = ship.getPlanet();

         if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) errors.rejectValue("name", "Can't be null or Empty");
         if(StringUtils.isEmpty(planet)) errors.rejectValue("planet", "Can't be null or Empty");
         if(name.length() > 50) errors.rejectValue( "name", "Can't be more than 50 chars");
         if(planet.length() > 50) errors.rejectValue("planet", "Can't be more than 50 chars");

    }

}
```

2. changes in controller to use this validator

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class ShipController {

    @Autowired ShipRepo shipRepo;

    @Autowired ShipValidator shipValidator;

    @PostMapping("/ships")
    public Ship saveShip(@RequestBody Ship ship, BindingResult result) {
        shipValidator.validate(ship, result);

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            //TODO: add your exception handling logic and handle these errors           
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in properties");
        }

        return shipRepo.save(ship);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i now it. But there is a problem: I can't use "spring validation" :( This is a task for applying for an internship and one of the conditions is not to add new dependencies.

Comment: validation is part of spring core and you don't have to add any new dependency in your code

Comment: in pom.xml i have dependences: spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-aop, spring-webmvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, but i can't add annotation Size or Max or somesing else. Idea asks to add dependency javax.validation... Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: I have updated answer with custom validation and how it can be used in controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know that it is possible))